# Shall we test text printed on console / command prompt using unit testing framework?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, command-line

I am developing one command line based tool. I am testing it with NUnit. I would like to know inputs about shall we test text printed on command prompt?

For example, if user gives wrong command line options then program prints text about how to use program. Shall we test this text also? Is it over-testing or everyone does it? If yes then how to test the text printed on command prompt using NUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it matters, then it's probably worthwhile testing.

This question and answer deals with how to do it: [Grabbing the output sent to Console.Out from within a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139274/grabbing-the-output-sent-to-console-out-from-within-a-unit-test)