# Testing console in and out console application in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a problem with testing "Console in" and "Console out" in a C# console application.

If I use Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine I can use NUnit framework to test the application, but if I use a helper class for in and output to console I cannot get it to work.

The helper class is https://open.kattis.com/download/Kattio.cs and uses a BufferedStream to write to the Console, but I cannot get my test to read it...

It uses A StreamReader for "Console in" but I get a "NoMoreTokenException" which I guess that it don't get any input...

I would like to use the helper class but I cannot test with it...

Ex:
Testcase:

```
    [Test]
    public void test_hello_world ()
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter ()) {              
            Console.SetOut (sw);
            using (var sr = new StringReader ("Start")) {
                Console.SetIn (sr);
                MainClass.Main(new string[]{});
                string expected = "Hello World!\n";
                Assert.AreEqual (sw.ToString (), expected);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ex: Code that work:

```
    string line = "";
    if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("Start"))
        line = "Hello World!";
    else
        line = "No such luck!";
    Console.WriteLine (line);
```

Ex: Code that don't work:

```
        string line = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner ();
        if (sc.Next ().Equals ("Start"))
            line = "Hello World!";
        else
            line = "No such luck!";
        BufferedStdoutWriter outWritter = new BufferedStdoutWriter ();
        outWritter.WriteLine (line);
        outWritter.Flush ();
```

Anyone having any insight on how to solve this?

Comment: If you look at [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx55zca2(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Console.OpenStandardInput`, it says _This method can be used to reacquire the standard input stream after it has been changed by the SetIn method._  I take that to mean that it's undoing the `Console.SetIn` and so it's actually reading from the console instead of your `StringReader`.

Comment: You might be able to pull this off by starting up your program in a separate process and passing the input and getting the output from it.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/q/2139274/126014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @juharr mentioned in the comment that calling Console.OpenStandardInput will reset the input stream. So you need to make the helper class testable for console streams. (*Only If you are allowed to change the implementation*).

First the Tokenizer class can be updated to use the console Reader as default TextReader:

```
public class Tokenizer
{
    string[] tokens = new string[0];
    private int pos;

    // StreamReader reader; Changed to TextReader
    TextReader reader;

    public Tokenizer(Stream inStream)
    {
        var bs = new BufferedStream(inStream);
        reader = new StreamReader(bs);
    }

    public Tokenizer()
    {
        // Add a default initializer as Console Input stream reader.
        reader = Console.In;
    }

    // ...... Rest of the code goe here...............
    // .....................
}
```

Also change the Buffer output writer to following:

> **Updated** - Constructor will accept other streams as well.

```
public class BufferedStdoutWriter
{
    public TextWriter Writer;

    public BufferedStdoutWriter() 
    {
        // Use default writer as console output writer
        this.Writer = Console.Out;
    }

    public BufferedStdoutWriter(Stream stream)
    {
        Writer = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(stream));
    }
    public void Flush()
    {
        Writer.Flush();
    }

    public void Write<T>(T value)
    {
        Writer.Write(value);
    }

    public void WriteLine<T>(T value)
    {
        Writer.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

*similarly can implementation of more functions if required.*

Now your test will successfully pass for **EX: Code that don't work** snippet.